# Pass the arguments received in C down to bash script

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have the following piece of C code that is being called with arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system( "/home/user/script.sh" );
    return 0;
}
```

how do i pass all arguments received down to script.sh?

Comment: By using [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to set up the string?

Comment: Forgive me for asking this but: Why write a C program that calls a shell script? It just seems like such a silly thing to do

Answer (score 3):

You could synthesize some string (escaping naughty characters like quote or space when needed, like [Shell related utility functions of *Glib*](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html) do) for [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

But (on Linux and Posix) you really want to call [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) without using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

You may want to read (in addition of the man page I linked above) : [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: No, you should be able to read the man page or the book I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for the [execv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) function. It will grant to you to execute a specific file passing to it some optional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try something next:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() {
    system("cat /etc/passwd");

    extern char * const environ[];
    char * const command[] = {"mylsname", "-lR", "/", NULL};
    execve("/bin/ls", command, environ);
    perror("execve");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: You forgot a `perror("execve"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` just before the last `}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snprintf()` function to frame a string. For example, `snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * 64, "/home/user/script.sh %s", argv[1]);` and use `system(filename);`

Comment: Then try running the original program as `./a.out  "foo; rm -rf $HOME" cc` but backup your data before trying. And it should be `system(filename)` without double quotes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for pointing out the quotes in `system()`. If somebody really has to run `rm -rf $HOME` why the way suggested by you? Why a down vote?